# How can i download current emails on server using outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, webmail

A friend of mine used to read all his email using the squirrel webmail client and now he wants to start using outlook.

The problem is that when we configured the client with imap, none of the existing emails on the server are downloaded to outlook. Is there an option or something that we have to check in order to do download all those old emails?

The main purpose of downloading all the messages from the webmail account is to later export all email addresses.

He has a 1and1 hosting/email account and is using outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

I have found that creating a pop3 connection to the server i was able to download all the current messages to outlook. now i can export all the data needed. 
It is recommended to use IMAP to sync email but for my main purpose of downloading all the emails i had to use pop3.

Update: keep in mind that only the headers will be download, you need to tell outlook to download complete item including attachments.